# Clean way to convert types using delete and generics

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have an object of type `A`, that I wish to convert into type `B`. The easiest way with basic immutability is to shallow clone this object and delete the extraneous properties.

```
type A = B & {
  prop1;
}

type B = {
  prop2;
}

const example = (oldA: A): B => {
  const newB = { ...oldA };
  delete newB.prop1;
  return newB as B;
}
```

Without assigning the type using `as`, TypeScript doesn't understand the return value is the correct return type.

I don't like casting with `as` whenever possible as this is very error prone. If I assign the temporary variable as type `A`, then I cannot delete without getting an error

```
const newB: A = { ..oldA }
```

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional

After reading online, I see I can use this notation;

```
const example = (oldA: A): B => {
  const newB: Partial<Pick<A, 'prop1'>> & Omit<A, 'prop1'> = { ...oldA };
  delete newB.prop1;
  return newB;
}
```

This works nicely, but I want to reuse this as a generic. I have tried the generic type below but I get two errors

```
type PartialProperty<X, Y> = Partial<Pick<X, Y>> & Omit<X, Y>
```

> Type 'Y' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof X'

> Type 'Y' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'

How can I correctly write the TypeScript definition as a reusable generic?

Comment: Why not [destructuring](https://tsplay.dev/N9PXow)?

Comment: What is your actual question? Is it "how do I write `PartialProperty` without error?" If so, you just need to `Y` to `keyof X` (and let's use the conventional `K` instead of the possibly-confusing `Y`) like [this](//tsplay.dev/mM15km). If that fully addresses your question I'm happy to write up an, if you'd first [edit] the question to make it obvious what the question is (change the title, move the `PartialProperty` definition to the top of the body, and possibly add a little context for what you're doing). If not, what am I missing? (If you reply please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz fair point, I wasn't explict; question updated. Your solution works nicely. If you do a write up I will upvote and accept your anser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `Pick<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) requires that `K` be assignable to `keyof T`, and [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) requires that `K` be assignable to some keylike type (`string | number | symbol`, also known as `PropertyKey`).

The problem with your `PartialProperty` definition is that your second, "key" argument (which you are calling `Y` but I will call `K` because that's more conventional) is not constrained at all.  You can't pass it as the second type argument to `Pick` or `Omit` unless you [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to the appropriate key type.  In a generic type parameter declaration like `type Foo<T> = ...` you can add a constraint like `type Foo<T extends XXX> = ...` so that any type argument passed in a `T` must be assignable to `XXX`.

Here's how it looks for `PartialProperty`:

```
type PartialProperty<X, K extends keyof X> =
    Partial<Pick<X, K>> & Omit<X, K>
```

That compiles without error because now `K` is constrained to `keyof X`, which satisfies both `Pick` (since `K` extends `keyof X`) and `Omit` (since `K` extends `keyof X` which extends `PropertyKey`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGxgg9pJIA8AGgDRQDSUEAHsBAHYAmAzlANYQhYBmUhAfFAC8AWABQUCbEQp0+GMgDGrIqTJ8BAMigB5ALbJgK8nyA)